# "Science journal” vs. “science magazine”

Tags: differences, nouns, terminology

What is the difference between the terms *journal* and *magazine*? Is it correct to call a magazine a journal?

For example, I found the *Journal of Radio Electronics* and the *Radio-Electronics Magazine*, and I was confused.

If both terms are correct, why does English need both?

Comment: THe title of this question seems to be in a different direction thatn the content. Can you fix one or the other so we know what to answer for you? Do you want to know if a journal is of higher quality than magazine, or do you want to know correctness of usage?

Comment: @Mitch, I want to know correctness of usage and differences in meaning, because a translation doesn't provide this details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In science, “journal” is specifically used for **peer-reviewed** periodicals, whereas a “magazine” can be anything.

That doesn’t mean it always works out that way, but it is the expectation.

Comment: What about 'Ladies Home Journal'?... Oh, you said that, there are exceptions.

Comment: @Mitch I was unaware that that publication was held to be in the “science” domain.

Comment: It was not clear from the beginning that the question was limited to science.